# How to change my Eclipse theme like RadRails'?

Tags: eclipse, themes

I really like the theme of RadRails for rails development. How to change my java development theme same like that. Need I download a new theme or just use the RadRails' theme?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Eclipse Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme). Here is my blog about that: http://blog.firdau.si/2011/01/27/fresh-look-for-your-eclipse-editor/